# Serilog TcpSink Not throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcp, serilog

Is there any way to track if end-point is available for Tcp Sink logging ? 
For example  locally on my machine I do not have FileBeat setup, while its working on Staging machine.

The way I initialize Logger

```
private readonly ILogger _tcpLogger;


public TcpClient(IOptions<ElasticSearchConfig> tcpClientConfig)
    {
        var ip = IPAddress.Parse(tcpClientConfig.Value.TcpClientConfig.IpAddress);

        _tcpLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     .WriteTo.TCPSink(ip, tcpClientConfig.Value.TcpClientConfig.Port, new TcpOutputFormatter())
                     .CreateLogger();
    }
```

and simple method  just to submit log

```
public void SubmitLog(string json) 
      { 
      _tcpLogger.Information(json);
      }
```

And in my case when its submitting json string locally, it just goes nowhere and I would like to get an exeption/message back.

ideally on  json submit, but during initialization is Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to a Serilog logger is meant to be a safe operation and never throw exceptions, and [that's by design](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability). Thus any exceptions that happen when sending those messages would only appear in the `SelfLog` - if you enable it.

e.g.

```
// Write Serilog errors to the Console
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));
```

The example above is, of course, just to illustrate the `SelfLog` feature... You'll choose where/how to display or store these error messages.

---

Now, if the operation you're logging is important enough that you'd want to guarantee it succeeds (or throws exception if it doesn't) then you should use [Audit Logging](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/october-serilog-update/), i.e. Use `.AuditTo.TCPSink(...)` instead of `.WriteTo.TCPSink(...)`

Comment: by any chance you would know what wrong Iam doing there as  no exception accured

``` var tcpAudit = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.TCPSink(ip, config.Value.TcpClientConfig.Port, new TcpOutputFormatter()).CreateLogger();

            _tcpLogger = new LoggerConfiguration().AuditTo.Logger(tcpAudit).CreateLogger();```

Comment: @DevyDev I'm not sure I understand what your goal is with the code snippet above, as you are wrapping a logger that is configured via `WriteTo` into the `AuditTo` so it you won't see any exceptions given that the `WriteTo` will swallow exceptions. I think you are looking for something like `_tcpLogger = new LoggerConfiguration().AuditTo.TCPSink(ip, config.Value.TcpClientConfig.Port, new TcpOutputFormatter()).CreateLogger();`

Comment: Sir, do not want to  sound rude but have you tried this code your self ? 

As  I am getting an error, that TCPSink is not available at this point. Or  I am missing some nugget/import ? 

At this momment I have 
    using Serilog;
    using Serilog.Events;
    using Serilog.Formatting;
    using Serilog.Sinks.Network;

Comment: @DevyDev It seems that the `TCPSink` you are using has not been updated to support [audit logging](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/october-serilog-update/) yet. You can [open an issue in the project or send a pull request](https://github.com/pauldambra/Serilog.Sinks.Network). In the meantime, your best bet is to use the `SelfLog` as per my example in the answer.

Comment: I have decided to simply use .Net TcpClient and just build wrapper around it this time. 

Thanks for your help anyway !